# How to customize and add extra elements to Sympy plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

I have a few questions about what how to work with graphics, using Sympy.

My code:

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols("x y")
plot_implicit(Eq(x**2 + y**2, 4), (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3))
```

1) The graph is obtained stretched along the x axis.

[image]

How to make so that the curve looked like a circle?

2) How to add other elements to the chart. For example, the point O(0, 0) and the line y = x.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810880/display-two-sympy-plots-as-two-matplotlib-subplots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docstring of [plot.py](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/plotting/plot.py), you can get the backend wrapper of the Matplotlib axes and figure that SymPy uses, through `_backend` attribute, and then modify properties as any other Matplotlib objects. Check this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols("x y")
hp = plot_implicit(Eq(x**2 + y**2, 4), (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3))
fig = hp._backend.fig
ax = hp._backend.ax
xx = yy = np.linspace(-3,3)
ax.plot(xx,yy) # y = x
ax.plot([0],[0],'o') # Point (0,0)
ax.set_aspect('equal','datalim')
fig.canvas.draw()
```

The Sympy Plot objects have append and extend methods that allows add a Plot object to other, but this don't  work (at least for me and using Jupyter).

Another option is use only Matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
xx,yy = np.linspace(-3,3), np.linspace(-3,3)
x,y = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)
ax.contour(x, y, (x**2+y**2-4), [0]);
ax.plot([0],[0],"o")
ax.plot(xx,yy)
ax.set_aspect('equal','datalim')
```

Comment: The first option for me also not working. However, the second method is ideal! If use eval: `ax.contour(x, y, eval(str(a_symbolic_expression)), [0]);`.

Comment: I don't know why, but the first method is worked for me if I add `plt.ion()` at the beginning and `plt.show(block=True)` at the end. (Python 3.6.2, matplotlib 1.1.1)

Comment: With sympy 1.7.1 I needed `ax = hp._backend.ax[0]` to get the first of a list of axes.

Answer (score 1):

Sympy's [plot functions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#plot-class) have a parameter `aspect_ratio=` which can be the tuple `(1,1)` for an equal ratio.

They also [support `markers=` and `annotations=` keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469474/how-do-i-use-the-markers-parameter-of-a-sympy-plot/71478683#71478683).  These are lists of dictionaries towards matplotlib's [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) and [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) functions.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, plot_implicit

x, y = symbols("x y")
plot_implicit(Eq(x ** 2 + y ** 2, 4), (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3), aspect_ratio=(1, 1),
              markers=[{'args': [0, 0], 'color': "blue", 'marker': "o", 'ms': 5},
                       {'args': [[-3, 3], [-3, 3]], 'color': "blue", 'ls': '-', 'lw': 2}],
              annotations=[{'xy': (0, 0), 'text': "  0", 'ha': 'left', 'va': 'top', 'color': 'blue'},
                           {'xy': (2, 2), 'text': "x=y ", 'ha': 'right', 'va': 'bottom', 'color': 'blue'}])
```

[image: sympy plot with extra lines, markers and annotations]