# Display two Sympy plots as two Matplotlib subplots

Tags: matplotlib, sympy

This code

```
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x')
p1 = plot(x**2,(x,-2,2))
p2 = plot(x**3,(x,-2,2))
```

results in two separate plots.

Instead of two separate plots, I want to display them with matplotlib as subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plt.show()
```

How can I add `p1` and `p2`, so that they are displayed as subplots inside the matplotlib figure?

Comment: I might be wrong. But sympy's plot does not seem to take ```ax``` arguments and everything seems figure-based. I think the state of matplotlib still is: merging multiple figures is hacky at least, not recommended. (For this example it also makes not much sense to me to not use mpl directly; but maybe it will be different for your real task).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that sympy `Plot` creates its own figure and axes. It is not meant to draw to an existing axes.

You may however replace the axes the plot is drawn to by an existing axes prior to showing the sympy plot.

```py
from sympy import Symbol,plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def move_sympyplot_to_axes(p, ax):
    backend = p.backend(p)
    backend.ax = ax
    backend._process_series(backend.parent._series, ax, backend.parent)  # backend.process_series() no longer works
    backend.ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    backend.ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    backend.ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.close(backend.fig)
    

x=Symbol('x')
p1 = plot(x**2,(x,-2,2), show=False)
p2 = plot(x**3,(x,-2,2), show=False)


fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
move_sympyplot_to_axes(p1, ax)
move_sympyplot_to_axes(p2, ax2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My solution does not add `p1`, `p2` to the subplots directly. But (x,y) coordinates from them are captured and used instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import symbols
import numpy as np

from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot

# part 1
# uses symbolic plot of functions
x = symbols('x')

#p1, p2 = plot(x**2, x**3, (x, -2, 2))

# this plot will not show ...
# only produce 2 curves
p1, p2 = plot((x**2, (x, -2, 2)), \
                (x**3, (x, -2, 2)), \
                show=False)

# collect (x,y)'s of the unseen curves 
x1y1 = p1.get_points()  # array of 2D
x2y2 = p2.get_points() 

# part 2
# uses regular matplotlib to plot the data

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

# do subplot 1 
ax1.plot(x1y1[0], x1y1[1], 'g')  # plot x**2 in green
ax1.set_xlim([-2, 2])
ax1.set_xlabel('X1')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y1')
ax1.set_title('Line1')  # destroyed by another .title(); axis metho1

# do subplot 2
ax2.plot(x2y2[0], x2y2[1], 'r')  # plot x**3 in red
ax2.set_xlim([-2, 2])
ax2.set_xlabel('X2')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y2')
ax2.set_title('Line2')

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4) # set space between subplots

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image: output]

Comment: While less general and maybe not what OP asked, i see this as viable alternative in some cases!

Comment: I am trying to draw a circle in one plot but the get_points doesn't quite work.

Comment: @DipanMehta  Please ask it as a new question, so more people (inc me) can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a plotgrid to get 2 or more plots in one figure.
See also: [sympy.plotting.PlotGrid()](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#plotgrid-class)

Here's a working example:

```py
import sympy as sp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# define functions
x = symbols('x')
f = sin(x)
g = cos(x)

# create separate plots
p1 = plot(f, show=False, xlim=(-pi, pi), line_color='blue', legend=True)
p2 = plot(g, show=False, xlim=(-pi, pi), line_color='red', legend=True)

# create a plotgrid with 2 rows and 1 column
plotgrid = sp.plotting.PlotGrid(2, 1, p1, p2, show=False, size=(5., 3.5))
plotgrid.show()
```

Resulting plot:

[image: subplots in sympy by using plotgrid]

Answer (score 0):

`sympy` provides a built-in class, `PlotGrid`, for this purpose. The first two parameters are the size of the grid, then `Plot`s-objects.

Notice that `Plot`-objects may contains simultaneous plots, `plot(x**2, x**3, (x,-2,2))`.

```py
from sympy.plotting.plot import plot, PlotGrid
from sympy.abc import x


# create a Plot-objects for each graph
p1 = plot(x**2,(x,-2,2), show=False)
p2 = plot(x**3,(x,-2,2), show=False)
p_mix = plot(x**3, x**2, (x,-2,2), show=False)

# manage the "subplots"

# horizontally
PlotGrid(1, 2, p1, p2)
# vertically
PlotGrid(2, 1, p1, p2)
# grid
PlotGrid(3, 2, p1, p2, p1, p2, p_mix)
```

Here the result for the grid layout

- general grid layout
  [image]

---

By doing a step further one can make your own *backend* to customize the plot process and keep the code clean.

Here just a sample example to add *title* and *subtitles* to plots **but the process can easily extended to control ticks, labels, ...**

```
from sympy.plotting.plot import PlotGrid, MatplotlibBackend
from sympy.abc import x


class PlotGridBE(MatplotlibBackend):

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, title, *subtitles):
        cls.TITLE = title
        cls.SUBTITLES = subtitles
        return cls

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        for subtitle, ax in zip(list(self.SUBTITLES) + ['']*(len(self.ax)-len(self.SUBTITLES)),
                                self.ax):
            # do some axis stuffs here
            pass
            if subtitle:
                ax.set_title(subtitle)

        if self.TITLE:
            self.fig.suptitle(self.TITLE, fontsize=16)


# create PlotGrid instance
p = PlotGrid(1, 2, p1, p2, show=False)
# manually pass the backend
p.backend = PlotGridBE.factory('Title', 'subtitle1') # 'subtitle2' not used but still compatible 
# display the plot
p.show()
# save to file
p.save('./mix_and_custom.png')
```

[image]

... and to keep even more the code clean make your *subclass* of `PlotGrid`

```
# [...]: imports & MultiPlotBE from before

class MyPlotGrid(PlotGrid):

    BACKEND_ARGS = []

    def __init__(self, nrows, ncolumns, *args, show=True, size=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(nrows, ncolumns, *args, show=False, size=size, **kwargs)
        # notice: kwargs is never used (as in source code)!

        self.backend = PlotGridBE.factory(*self.BACKEND_ARGS)

        if show:
            self.show()


# fix the parameter of the backend
MyPlotGrid.BACKEND_ARGS = 'Title', 'subtitle_1'
# call the plot object
MyPlotGrid(1, 2, p1, p2)
```