# Combine sympy and matplotlib plots in one picture

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I need to build an expression graph and a graph set by an array of points, and return the images. To build an expression graph, I use `sympy.plot`, and to build a graph on points I use `matplotlib`.

Here is an example code:

```
from os import remove
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from sympy import plot, symbols

def plot_graphic(x, y, expression, file_name):
    file = '{}.png'.format(file_name)
    x1, y1 = list(x), list(y)
    plt.plot(x1, y1)
    plt.savefig(file)
    plt.close()
    del y1
    img = Image.open(file)
    remove(file)
    yield img

    x = symbols('x')
    plot(expression.args[1], (x, x1[0], x1[-1]), show=False).save(file)
    img = Image.open(file)
    remove(file)
    yield img
```

x, y are generators. How can I combine these images at one?

Comment: I'm going to guess that `sympy.plot` is using MatPlotLib to do the actual work here.

Comment: I did not find in the sympy documentation how to build a graph of the given points

Comment: i was going the other way with that. It looks like sympy.plot returns a regular MatPlotLib figure that you can use to add whatever plots you want additionally

Comment: sympy.plot returns a Plot object and I can not build it using matplotlib.

Comment: The second sentence at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html reads "Presently the plots are rendered using `matplotlib` as a backend"

Comment: I'm unclear as to how to get a reference to said backend from reading the docs though, so good question. I'll do some more research and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @MadPhysicist See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810880/display-two-sympy-plots-as-two-matplotlib-subplots/46813804#46813804 (including the comment by Sébastien Loisel)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Sympy has a method for plotting points. You need to create a `List2DSeries` object that does the necessary and add to the other graphics using the `append` method. The resulting code is shown below.

```
from os import remove
from PIL import Image
from sympy import plot, symbols
from sympy.plotting.plot import List2DSeries

def plot_graphic(x, y, expression, file_name):
    file = '{}.png'.format(file_name)
    x1, y1 = list(x), list(y)
    x = symbols('x')
    graph = plot(expression.args[1], (x, x1[0], x1[-1]), show=False, line_color='r')
    graph.append(List2DSeries(x1, y1))
    graph.save(file)
    img = Image.open(file)
    remove(file)
    return img
```

Comment: But can I use this method to add the separate points of another look/color, say red points, to the previously created graph p1 drawn with blue line?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution using the `get_points()` function in `sympy`. Here is an example for plotting two sets of data using Matplotlib

```
plots = sympy.plot(data0, data1, show=False)
for plot in plots:
   pts = plot.get_points()
   plt.plot(pts[0], pts[1])
plt.show()
```

You can also set all the parameters of `plt`, like axis limit and legend.

Comment: This didn't work for me when trying to get the points from a plot_implicit() plot.  I got lists containing some kind of interval object.