# Sympy implicit_plot always display x-axis at y=0

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I'm trying to plot ellipse using `sympy.implicit_plot`. The center of my ellipse is not at the origin. So, I set parameter `axis_center` of the function to move to the location of my ellipse accourdingly.

For example in my picture, the center is at (35, 35) and the semi-minor axis is 10, it does not need to display the location between y=0 to y=20, so I set the parameter `y_var=(y, 20, 60)` which display the y-axis between [20, 60].
But I notice that x-axis always stays at y=0 regardless of the range in `y_var`, what it does is removing the display the y-axis from the range between [0, 20].

I want the x-axis and y-axis to meet at y=20 like what matplotlib can do. Is it possible to do that?

[image: plot]

P.S. I use sympy because I need to plot multiple implicit functions along with the scatter data. I looked on the internet and found that sympy cannot do scatter plot. So, I plot the curve with sympy then move to matplotlib with this function
[Putting together plots of Matplotlib and Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325325/putting-together-plots-of-matplotlib-and-sympy)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sympy import plot_implicit, symbols


def get_rotation_matrix(deg):
    rad = np.deg2rad(deg)
    return np.array([[np.cos(rad), -np.sin(rad)],
                    [np.sin(rad), np.cos(rad)]])


def move_sympyplot_to_axes(p, ax):
    backend = p.backend(p)
    backend.ax = ax
    backend._process_series(backend.parent._series, ax, backend.parent)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), ha='right', x=1, labelpad=0)
    ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), ha='right', va='top', y=1, labelpad=0, rotation=0)
    plt.close(backend.fig)


a = 20
b = 10
u = get_rotation_matrix(60)

center= np.array((35, 35))


x, y = symbols('x y')

# ellipse function
f = ((x-center[0])/a)**2 + ((y-center[1])/b)**2 - 1

# plot
p = plot_implicit(f, (x, -20, 60), (y, 20, 60), aspect_ratio=(1,1), \
            axis_center =center.tolist(), xlabel="x", ylabel="y", \
    title="", show=False)


f, ax = plt.subplots()
move_sympyplot_to_axes(p, ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x-axis is staying at zero because of this line in `move_sympyplot_to_axes`:

```py
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
```

delete that line and your x axis will appear in the middle of your y axis. If you want your xaxis to start at y=20, replace that line with

```py
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 20))
```