# How to change sympy plot linestyle?

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to sympy in python.

When I tried to create a plot with sympy today, I was not able to change the linestyle. I find that the plot object in sympy has both 'line_color' attribute and 'linestyle' attribute.

I was able to use the line_color attribute to change color successfully, but the linestyle attribute did not work for me.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
x = symbols('x')
plot_1 = plot(x**2, xlim=[0,10], ylim=[0,10], show=False)
plot_2 = plot(0.5*x**2, xlim=[0,10], ylim=[0,10], show=False)
plot_1.extend(plot_2)
plot_1[0].linestyle='dashed'
plot_1[0].line_color='red'
plot_1.show()
```

[The output looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bRY7.png)

Comment: Within sympy, only the line color can be changed. It can be set directly via `plot(x**2, ..., line_color='green')`.  To change other properties, you might need to move the plot to matplotlib (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810880/display-two-sympy-plots-as-two-matplotlib-subplots/46813804#46813804)  including the comment about newer versions of sympy)

Comment: Thank you! It is helpful to confirm that. I hope future updates will allow for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

In a Jupyter Notebook you can use matplotlib magic and the `_backend` attribute of the sympy plot object to access all attributes of the corresponding matplotlib plot object:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
%matplotlib notebook
plot_1 = plot(x**2, xlim=[0,10], ylim=[0,10], show=False)
plot_2 = plot(0.5*x**2, xlim=[0,10], ylim=[0,10], show=False)
plot_1.extend(plot_2)
#plot_1[0].linestyle='dashed'
plot_1[0].line_color='red'
plot_1.show()
plot_1._backend.ax[0]._children[0].set_linestyle('dashed')
```

[image: Dashed line in a Jupyter notebook]