# How to change sympy plot properties in Jupyter with matplotlib methods

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, sympy, jupyter-lab

The following code in a script works as expected,

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
p = plot(x, x*(1-x), (x, 0, 1))
ax = p._backend.ax[0]
ax.set_yticks((0, .05, .25))
p._backend.fig.savefig('Figure_1.png')
```

[image]

but when I copy the code above in a notebook cell, this is what I get

[image]

If it is possible to manipulate the (hidden) attributes of a Sympy's `plot` when one works in a Jupyter notebook, how can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813804/7758804) of [Display two Sympy plots as two Matplotlib subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46810880/7758804), with inline mode in Jupyter, `p.backend(p)` must be used.
- *The problem is that [`sympy.plotting.plot.plot(*args, show=True, **kwargs)`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot.plot) creates its own figure and axes* and [`plots.show()`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/d2be7bacd2604e98a642f74028e8f0d7d6084f78/sympy/plotting/plot.py#L1872) displays the plot immediately.

  - Because of the way inline mode works, the plot is shown before the changes are implemented by `ax.set_yticks((0, .05, .25))`.
- **Tested in `python v3.12.0`, `matplotlib v3.8.1`, `sympy v1.11.1`.**

```py
from sympy import symbols, plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = symbols('x')
# note show=False, the default is True
p = plot(x, x*(1-x), (x, 0, 1), show=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

backend = p.backend(p)
backend.ax = ax
backend._process_series(backend.parent._series, ax, backend.parent)

backend.ax.set_yticks((0, .05, .25))
plt.close(backend.fig)

plt.show()
```

[image]

- In interactive mode `%matplotlib qt`, the code in the OP works fine.

```py
from sympy import symbols, plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib qt  # %matplotlib inline - to revert to inline

x = symbols('x')
p = plot(x, x*(1-x), (x, 0, 1))
ax = p._backend.ax[0]
ax.set_yticks((0, .05, .25))
```

---

### With a custom *backend* instance.

This has as the advantage that `matplotlib` should not be explicitly imported.

One should be aware of what you are doing: `sympy` provides a ready-to-use interface to plot functions on the fly, without the need to worry about (boring) mathematical technicality such as domain/range. If instead you try to act against such defaults you need to go back to the [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/plotting/plot.py#L1638) and do some reverse engineering.

In the OP, custom *ticks* are required, but by default the `MatplotlibBackend` sets a `linear` scale, for both x & y, from the [`sympy.plotting.plot.Plot`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/plotting/plot.py#L178) object, `xscale='linear', yscale='linear'`, which interfere with the [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks) method.

From the source code

```py
1467         if parent.yscale and not isinstance(ax, Axes3D):
1468             ax.set_yscale(parent.yscale)
```

By setting `parent.yscale` to `False` (or `None`, `''`) the condition will never be meet.

[`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) is built-in python method used for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.

```py
from sympy.plotting.plot import MatplotlibBackend
from sympy import symbols

class JupyterPlotter(MatplotlibBackend):

    def _process_series(self, series, ax, parent):        
        parent.yscale = False
        ax.set_yticks((0, .05, .25))  # custom yticks
        super()._process_series(series, ax, parent)


x = symbols('x')
p = plot(x, x*(1-x), (x, 0, 1), backend=JupyterPlotter)
```

[image]

Plots with special needs may require a special implementation, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74245624/7758804) is a different example.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html) indicates matplotlib is being used underneath. An example using this to adjust things is in [this answer to 'How to change sympy plot linestyle?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71468420/8508004):

> "you can use .... the _backend attribute of the sympy plot object to access all attributes of the corresponding matplotlib plot object"