# Adjust ticks in a sympy plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

I'm trying to use sympy's plotting capabilities, but I can't find a way to modify the `xticks`. Is that even possible? Since, according to the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html), sympy relies on *matplotlib*, I would think it is (maybe accessing the underlying *matplotlib*'s axis), but I couldn't find an example anywhere.

A MWE:

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t')
f = sp.Piecewise((0, t < 0), (0, t > 2), (1, True))

sp.plotting.plot(f, (t, -1, 3), ylim=(0, 1.5))

# change ticks
# ....
```

Any hint?

Cheers.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813804/12046409) explains how to move a plot from sympy to matplotlib. (One of the comments there explains about adaption to recent sympy versions)

Comment: That did the trick!! Thank you so much!!