# get_points in sympy plot_implicit

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy, implicit

I have been trying of solving an implicit equations using contour plot but I realized it was taking into account the singularities of my equation so I was obtaining wrong graphs. Because of this, I tried sympy.plot_implicit. Fortunately, it works properly but I have not found a proper way to set a label on the graphs produced by sympy.plot_implicit. For this aim, I need to obtain the points used by sympy.plot_implicit for producing its the graphs and use them into matplotlib. This way, I am obtainig correct solutions for my implicit equations and I can easily set labels for the graphs of the solutions. At this moment, I am facing many issues when I try to obtain the point from sympy.plot_implicit, I mean, when I only use  `sympy.plot` there is not any problem but the issues appear when I use `sympy.plot_implicit`.
I have attached the code, thank you in advance.
Best

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x,y,z

def z(x, y):
    return x - y

line = sp.plot(x**2,(x,-1,0), show=False)

#line = sp.plot_implicit(z(x, y), (x, 0, 1), (y, 0, 1), show=False)

x, y = line[0].get_points()

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `move_sympyplot_to_axes` function from [Display two Sympy plots as two Matplotlib subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813804/12046409), adapting one line as explained in its comments.

To get something in the legend, matplotlib's standard approach is to add a label to the specific element. In this case, the implicit area seems to be stored as a polygon inside `ax.patches`. Such a polygon will be shown as a colored rectangle in the legend.  In order to get a line, a custom legend element could be created.

As in this case the solution is represented as a thin polygon and not as a line `p1[0].get_points()` doesn't work.  However, you can extract the polygon's vertices from the matplotlib polygon patch:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x, y, z

def move_sympyplot_to_axes(p, ax):
    backend = p.backend(p)
    backend.ax = ax
    backend._process_series(backend.parent._series, ax, backend.parent)
    backend.ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    backend.ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    backend.ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    plt.close(backend.fig)

def z(x, y):
    return (x ** 2 + y ** 2 - 1) ** 3 - x ** 2 * y ** 3

p1 = sp.plot_implicit(z(x, y), (x, -1.5, 1.5), (y, -1.5, 1.5), show=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

move_sympyplot_to_axes(p1, ax)
# ax.patches[0].set_label("my label")
handles = [Line2D([], [], color=ax.patches[0].get_facecolor())]
ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=["my label"], loc='upper left')

vertices = ax.patches[0].get_path().vertices
ax.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], ls=':', color='gold', lw=10, alpha=0.5, zorder=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: sympy plot_implicit with a legend in matplotlib]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is a good solution. 
On the other hand, did you detect the problem using get_points?

Comment: `get_points` only works when the internal plotting representation is a curve. Here, the solution is represented as a thin polygon.