# plot with symbolic tick labels

Tags: sympy

I would like to draw plots which preserve symbolic meaning for certain numeric values.

In a `isympy` shell I can write:

```
T = Symbol('T')

plot(exp(x/T).subs(T, 5))
```

Which gives the following plot

[image]

I don't care much about the numeric tick labels in the plot. What I am interested in is where the x axis equals `T=5` the y axis should equal `e=2.718`. In other words I want to discard all tick labels on both axis and only have one tick label on the x axis for `T` and one label on the y axis for `e`.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Sympy and plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747474/sympy-and-plotting), you can customize a sympy plot via accessing `._backend.ax`. In my current version I needed `._backend.ax[0]`.

Here is how your plot could be adapted:

```py
from sympy import Symbol, plot, exp

t_val = 5
T = Symbol('T')
plot1 = plot(exp(x / T).subs(T, t_val))
fig = plot1._backend.fig
ax = plot1._backend.ax[0]
ax.set_xticks([t_val])
ax.set_xticklabels([str(T)])
e_val = exp(1).evalf()
ax.set_yticks([e_val])
ax.set_yticklabels(["e"]) # or ax.set_yticklabels([f"{e_val:.3f}"]) ?
ax.plot([t_val, t_val, 0], [0, e_val, e_val], color='dodgerblue', ls='--')
fig.canvas.draw()
```

[image: customizing sympy plot]