# 'Plot' object has no attribute '_backend' when using plot_implicit() from sympy

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, sympy

I am using the `plot_implicit()` function from `sympy`, and when I try and access the `matplotlib` backend like everyone says to do, I get the following error: `Plot` object has no attribute '_backend'

I have tried 'import spb' after doing 'pip install sympy_plot_backends'. I have also tried declaring explicitly `p = sympy.plot_implicit(...)` as compared to `p = plot_implicit(..)` which expectedly changed nothing.

```
import sympy

p = sympy.plot_implicit(formattedQ, show=False)
fig = p._backend.fig
fig.set_title("asdfj")
```

## Traceback

```
stderr:     fig = p._backend.figAttributeError: 'Plot' object has no    attribute '_backend'
```

Comment: The thing is I wanted to use the backend for a bunch of other styling things, not just the title

Answer (score 0):

In the current (1.18) sympy version, the old way to access the matplotlib isn't supported anymore.

Sympy's [plotting](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#plotting-function-reference) lists a number of elements you can change or add to a sympy plot. The list is quite long, but unfortunately not documented in detail. Examples are `title`, `label`, `xlabel`, `xscale`, `xlim`, ... You can also add `markers`, `rectangles` and `annotations` via lists of dictionaries.  See e.g. [How to customize and add extra elements to Sympy plots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71479487/12046409)

To add a title, you can just write `sympy.plot_implicit(..., title='my title')`.

If you need more matplotlib fine-tuning, you can "move the plot to matplotlib", as described in [Display two Sympy plots as two Matplotlib subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813804/12046409).

For your example, the code could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import plot_implicit, Eq, S
from sympy.abc import x, y

def move_sympyplot_to_axes(p, ax):
    backend = p.backend(p)
    backend.ax = ax
    backend._process_series(backend.parent._series, ax, backend.parent)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), ha='right', x=1, labelpad=0)
    ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), ha='right', va='top', y=1, labelpad=0, rotation=0)
    plt.close(backend.fig)

formattedQ = Eq (x**(S(2)/3) + y**(S(2)/3), 8)
p = plot_implicit(formattedQ, (x, -25, 25), (y, -25, 25), show=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
move_sympyplot_to_axes(p, ax)
ax.set_title('formattedQ')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image: move sympy plot to matplotlib]